Visual Studio Code in Mac OSX Sequoia does not update itself

This is Mac OSX 15.1.1 Sequoia (M4 chip). Visual Studio Code was properly installed (it is in ~/Applications folder). All formerly known remedies like "unquarantine" did not help.
Anyone can share a solution, please?
sudo xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine "Visual Studio Code.app"
Result(s):
xattr: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: 'Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Frameworks/Code Helper (Plugin).app/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeResources'
